# Проблемы получения данных из переменных в MySQL

Tags: mysql, blob

Как получить данные из переменной? Делаю простой запрос:

```
SELECT @val1 := count(`ID`) as `val1`, @val1 as `val2` FROM `orders`;
```

Получаю:

```
val1    val2
100500  [BLOB - NULL]
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в val2 получить данные?

Comment: Попробовал. хм. именно с count не работает ... причем `select @val1 from (select @val1:=count(id) from table) A` отлично работает ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что в случае использования агрегированной функции MySQL выполняет присвоение в последний момент и порядок операций задать вряд ли удастся. Тогда такие варианты:

Один:

```
SELECT @val1 := COUNT(*) FROM orders;
SELECT @val1 AS val1, @val1 AS val2 FROM orders;
```

Два, помедленнее:

```
SELECT (SELECT @val1 := COUNT(*) FROM orders) AS val1, @val1 AS val2 FROM orders;
```

Три:

```
SELECT @val1 AS val1, CAST(@val1 AS DECIMAL) AS val2 
FROM orders
JOIN (SELECT @val1 := COUNT(*) FROM orders) t;
```

Подобная ситуация [описана в доках](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)

> In a SELECT statement, each select expression is evaluated only when
>   sent to the client. This means that in a HAVING, GROUP BY, or ORDER BY
>   clause, referring to a variable that is assigned a value in the select
>   expression list does not work as expected